# Application pool already exists error or Access denied

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-on-prem, web-application, application-pool

I have a problem with creating a web application and application pool.

I use this code:

```
New-SPWebApplication -Name $Name -Port $port -HostHeader $header -URL $url -ApplicationPool $ppn -ApplicationPoolAccount (Get-SPManagedAccount $ppa)
```

Normally it create a application pool with web application and everything is OK, but after few times deleting and recrating it I get now an error now and it says that Application Pool already exists. Although when I deleted the web application I've deleted the Application Pool and Databases if the web application had sites.

I thought i would delete it manually, the application pool, but i cannot find it, where it exists? I've checked in IIS, i've checked in applicationHost.config, I don't understand where the traces of that application pool can be.

When i try to create a web application and to choose that name, it says access is denied. I think the application pool is corrupt.

I've tried to restart the server as well, it did not help.

Anyone maybe can advise?

Comment: Did you try to recycle the IIS using IIS_RESET before trying to create the account again?

Answer (score 0):

What i am suspecting, it is either corrupt or stuck in the memory which is causing the issue. I would try below steps:

- Go to `service console` on Server -> Stop & Start World wide web service. Peform this on all server in the SharePoint farm
- Stop the IIAdmin service using the command line `NET STOP iisadmin /y`  and Start it `NET START iisadmin`, Perform it on all servers in SharePoint Farm.
- Also check the Central admin and if you can see any traces over here. `goto >Central admin > Security > Configure Service Accounts >` on this page, click on **Select an account for this component** and make sure that App Pool not listed here.
- Also Close the PowerShell cosnole and reopen it as Admin.
- at the end may be you need to clear the configuration cache on the SharePoint servers.